# Filter Nested JSON based on the Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON  Object want to the filter the JSON based on the Object

```
var fromValues  = {table1: true, schema1: true, database: true, column1: true} 



 const treeMetaData = [
    {
      name  :  'database',
      checked : false,
      schemas  : [
        {
          name  : "schema1",
          checked : false,
          tables : [
            {
              name  : "table1",
              checked : false,
              columns  : [
                {
                  name  : "column1",
                  checked : false,
                }, 
                {
                  name  : "column2",
                  checked : false,
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

want the output like this

```
export const treeMetaData = [
    {
      name  :  'database',
      checked : true,
      schemas  : [
        {
          name  : "schema1",
          checked : true,
          tables : [
            {
              name  : "table1",
              checked : true,
              columns  : [
                {
                  name  : "column1",
                  checked : true,
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Values of the checked has gets true and removed the false checked values from the columns array object. 
What is the better approach if formValues are getting change and the result would change accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could build new objects.

```js
function filter(array, filters) {
    return array.reduce((r, { name, checked, ...o }) => {
        if (filters[name]) r.push(Object.assign(
            { name, checked: true },
            ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({
                [k]: Array.isArray(v)
                    ? filter(v, filters)
                    : v
            }))
        ));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var fromValues = { table1: true, schema1: true, database: true, column1: true },
    treeMetaData = [{ name: 'database', checked: false, schemas: [{ name: "schema1", checked: false, tables: [{ name: "table1", checked: false, columns: [{ name: "column1", checked: false }, { name: "column2", checked: false }] }] }] }],
    result = filter(treeMetaData, fromValues);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in React or one of the JS frameworks? That could help you manage state. You could turn formValues into a state object and then pass in a function for the boolean of that state property in your treeMetaData.

For example in React:

```
import react, { useState } from 'react';


export default function Example() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({table1: false, table2: false})

    const treeMetaData = [
     {
      name: "table1",
      checked: (state.table1),
      whatever: []
     }
    ]


    return (
        <div>
            {treeMetaData[0].checked.toString()}
        </div>

    )

   }
```

This returns false like it should. I'm not saying this a great way to do whatever you're doing, but it does dynamically return your state.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you have your fields laid out like this?  Why the checked field?  fromValues just being an object with booleans doesn't really make sense either.  Would you ever have false props?  Probably not.

```
const filter = {
  database: 'database',
  schema: ['schema1'],
  table: ['table1'],
  column: ['column1'],
}
```

Probably makes more sense.  You could take it a step further and do:

```
const filter = [
{
  database: 'database',
  schema: ['schema1'],
  table: ['table1'],
  column: ['column1'],
},
{
  database: 'database2',
  schema: ['schema2'],
  table: ['table2'],
  column: [column2],
},
]
```

For doing batched queries to multiple database.

Assuming you don't have specific requirements for this, just an object structure that looks more or less like `treeMetaData`, I think it would be wise to rethink how you go about doing this.  It will also make the code you write to handle it cleaner.